# Map Series Extent with Rotation not working properly

Tags: arcgis-pro, map-series

In ArcGIS Pro I have enable map series with % extents and the map series work properly. Then when I try and rotate the layers or dataframe and refresh/re-enable map series the map extents no longer work correctly. I do not have this issue when using arcmap. Any suggestions?